# How to delete "Program Files" folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

I replaced my current drive C with a brand new drive and installed Windows 7 on the new drive.  I took the old Drive C: and added it to a different SATA port and made it Drive E:  I then renamed the Program Files folder to BillyBobProgramFiles and then tried to delete the folder ... to no avail.  I ran into the TrunstedInstaller problem.

I then took control of the files and gave myself full access.  I then rebooted the computer.  I then signed back on as myself "CTB_DESKTOP\CTBlankenship" (which in and of itself has "Administrator" privledges) and tried to delete the folder again.  I get the error message "You must get permission from 'CTB_DESKTOP\CTBlankenship" to delete these files'.  I'm stumped.  How can I get permission from myself to delete the files I want to delete?

Comment: Have you tried http://superuser.com/questions/157108/deleting-windows-system-folder?rq=1 or http://superuser.com/questions/395803/windows-7-unable-to-delete-folder-in-programs-files?rq=1?

Comment: This should work: http://superuser.com/a/423821/96662

Answer (score -1):

sethc.exe is the program run when sticky keys activated. Using this neat little "hack" you can log yourself in as the NTAUTHORITY\System account, the Windows equivalent of the root user.

1. Rename C:\Windows\System32\sethc.exe to sethc.exe.old
2. Make a copy of cmd.exe and rename it to sethc.exe
3. Logoff, and at the login screen, strike the shift key five times.
4. Do whatever your heart desires. You can even start explorer.exe from the command prompt.

You may wish to remove sethc.exe and move sethc.exe.old to sethc.exe again once you are done.